# Can onclick take a function in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

THis is what I want.

onclick="pager(function2();)

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context around this?  does `function2` return a value you want to pass to `pager()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the semicolon:

```
onclick="pager(function2())"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BQYVV/

You are not passing a function to a function, but just a value. When the element is clicked, `function2()` is called, and it's return value becomes an argument to the `pager()` function. If `function2` does not return anything, pager will receive `undefined` as an argument.

Comment: seems like adding an extra semi-column is not always a good thing :) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+extra+semicolon

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="function2(function1());">Click me</a>
<script>
    function function2(msg) { alert(msg); };
    function function1() { return "Hello World"; };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What's not working in your code?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to make it work

```
<p onclick="pager(function2())">Click Me</p>
```

```
​function pager(fn)​{
    return fn;
}
  function function2(){
    alert('hello');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, *please* don't use in-line script, assign the click handler, like this:

```
$("div").click(function() {
  pager(function2());
});
```

This is if you wanted to assign it to all `<div>` elements, if you wanted it on a particular element via ID, like this: `<a href="#" id="bob">Link</a>`.  You would use `$("#bob")` instead of `$("div")`.  [There's a full list of selectors here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), if you're familiar with CSS, you'll feel right at home.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I ended up using. thanks for the help.